# MySQL database for storing city bounding boxes and names

Tags: mysql, database-design, spatial

I need to design a mysql database which contains a table of cities which supports only a single query - given a point, return the city (or cities) which it falls in. I have the bounding box for each city. What should the column look like to store the city bounding box to fully take advantage of mysql's spatial-indexing, multiple POINT columns? POLYGON? And what does the query look like.

Most discussion I've seen of spatial indexing involves the inverse question - given a bounding box, return the set of entries which have a POINT column which falls within the bounding box, which they are able to do using MBRWITHIN to obtain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Not a full answer, but too long for a Comment.)

With 200 cities with 'retangular' bounding boxes, virtually anything will do.  Even a simple table without a `SPATIAL` index, but with `INDEX(latitude), INDEX(longitude)`.

3 million cities, on the other hand, needs some serious indexing.  `SPATIAL`, as you are asking about, is probably the 'right' way to do it.

[*Here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng) is an efficient way to do it without `SPATIAL`, using `PARTITIONing` and special code instead.  (However, the code given is aimed at a different problem, so it is not directly applicable.)

Comment: Can convert these to bounding boxes. https://github.com/JamesChevalier/cities/tree/master/united_states

Answer (score 0):

Think - the spatial indexes would be right, but just some tricks which we use on one search project with MySQL 5.5

Look for problem from other side - how many cities could be on 1 degree lat/lon?

IF exclude some countries like Malta (where my son walking from Home to School cross 3 cities for 15 minutes) - common answer will be not too much.

So, with index for lat and longitude queries like:

```
SELECT something FROM cities 
WHERE 
(lat > xx - 1degree AND lat < xx + 1 degree) AND (lon > xx - 1degree AND lon < xx + 1 degree) 
AND (other conditions such as - distance from point and etc)
```

would be fast, just because first layer of filters return You less than 100 rows

this logic was successfully used with 10M+ rows tables

Comment: Maybe I know too little about sql, but how does sql avoid checking all 10M+ cities to see if they fall within the range? Also, is there any advantage to this syntax over BETWEEN?

Comment: SQL check all Cities, where City Centre +- 1 (or 0.5) degree from selected ... that all, choose any country and count number of cities on 150x150km - result will be not huge, over this 10-200 cities You can run any additional functions. BETWEEN - not a problem, I just provide as it in source. Really - I not sure how many Cities in the world? Our project was about objects in distance range from named City and it work as described

Comment: New York metro is the largest 'city' in area - 8683 sqKm [_ref_](http://www.citymayors.com/statistics/largest-cities-area-125.html) , so its bounding box is very probably more than 1 degree in latitude and/or longitude.

Comment: So, to make the single query work, you need to find the max size (lat and lng) of bounding boxes, not just 1 degree.  This gets problematical near the poles, where 10 degrees longitude is not very far.

Comment: Also, MySQL will not make full use of `INDEX(lat, lng)`; it will only use `lat`.

Comment: @RickJames - 1x1 degree - it is 60nautical miles x 60nautical miles ;-) it is 108x108km which is little more or less same as New York City, but more important other - how many cities around New York? It not ideal trick - but it work where Spatial index not available - take 2 degree if want check all cities in 100 km radius from NY centre ... how many of them? Than calculate polygon and distance or anything. Again - it is not ideal, but was work on old MySQL. Original question was not about SPA saloon closed to Subway station, but about - given point with relation to City.

Comment: Sitka, Alaska is mostly a big island -- about 2 deg by 2 deg.  Jiuquan, China, at 168K sqKm -- about 5deg lat by 10deg lng.

Comment: Yeah, it gets messy around NYC, LA, etc.

Comment: I get about 300 "cities" within 1 degree of the center of NYC and Boston.

Comment: Manila, Craiova, and Cebu each have about 600 cities within a degree.

Comment: 600 - not too much when we talking about 3 million? isn't right? I not dispute about polygons - it must be better, but a lot of  people still work on MySQL 5.0 ...

Comment: What about 5.0?  (Other than InnoDB does not have `SPATIAL`.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution.

Assumptions:

- Possibly millions of cities.
- Most cities are not very big.
- The list of cities, and their 'bounding boxes', is mostly unchanging.  (Occasional updates/additions will not hurt this algorithm.)

Design:

- Each city has a unique `id`, but it will not be the `PRIMARY KEY` in the table.
- The design will take advantage of the "clustering" nature of InnoDB's `PRIMARY KEY`.
- Two extra `SMALLINT` columns:  `lat2` = `FLOOR(latitude * 2)`, `lng2` = `FLOOR(longitude * 2)`
- `PRIMARY KEY(lat2, lng2, id)` -- Notes: Unique; all cities overlapping a spot will be "clustered" together, making the lookup efficient.
- lat2 is 35mi / 56km wide; lng2 is that wide, or less.
- Near the poles there are not many cities, and they are relatively small.
- Each "city" will be represented in the table *as many times as necessary* --  That is, a 'large' city or one that spills across a lat2 or lng2 boundary will be represented multiple times, but...
- There will be only perhaps 10% overhead due to such duplication.  (That one 'city' in China will show up a few hundred times.  But some cities of 1M will fit in one 'square'.)
- `*2` is a guess as to what is optimal.  `*1` would lead to too many cities to do secondary filtering on.  `*10` would lead to more cities having to be duplicated.  It's hard to predict the optimal spot; my gut says that the multiplier won't matter much.

Lookup - given that you are at $lat, $lng, then the list of cities you are possibly in is

```
SELECT id
    FROM ...
    WHERE lat2 = FLOOR($lat * 2)
    WHERE lng2 = FLOOR($lng * 2)
```

That will return a few, maybe a few dozen, rows.  Then `JOIN` to the table table of cities (or have all the data in this table).  Check each one against the bounding box (or polygon), thereby whittling the list down to very few cities.

This design allows searching *much* faster than checking the millions or rows.  Possibly even less work than with a `SPATIAL` index.